# Module - IIFE isn't automatically called

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created a module but it is not automatically rendered in my page, I have to manually call Board.renderBoard() in the console for the Board to appear. What am I doing wrong ?

here's the entire code:

```
const Board = (() => {
  const board = document.querySelector('.board');
  const createTiles = () => {
    tile = document.createElement('div');
    tile.classList.add('tile');
    return tile;
  };
  const renderBoard = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      createTiles();
      board.appendChild(createTiles());
    }
  };
  return {
    renderBoard
  };
})();
```

Comment: it's just an exposing/revealing module pattern, if you want renderBoard to execute once on load, call it once before the return.

Comment: The function is not called because you never call it. You only create it and expose it as a method to `Board`.

Comment: sidenote: `const tile = ...` please declare all your variables

Comment: Now it works. Problem solved, thank you both.

Comment: @Thomas I forgot, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created a module but it is not automatically rendered in my page, I have to manually call Board.renderBoard() in the console for the Board to appear.

JS doesn't just call function unless you tell it to call these functions.

Your module simply defines an object `Board` with a method `renderboard`. There's nothing that tells JS to call this method.

You could add the call right after declaring the module.

```
const Board = (() => {
  ...
})();
Board.renderBoard();
```

But if all you want is that the code initially builds the board you can do:

```
(() => {
  const board = document.querySelector('.board');
  const createTiles = () => {
    const tile = document.createElement('div'); // please declare your variables
    tile.classList.add('tile');
    return tile;
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    createTiles(); // what is this line for?
    board.appendChild(createTiles());
  }
})();
```

or

```
(() => {
  const board = document.querySelector('.board');
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    const tile = document.createElement('div');
    tile.classList.add('tile');
    board.appendChild(tile);
  }
})();
```

or maybe even

```
document.querySelector('.board').innerHTML = '<div class="tile"></div>'.repeat(9);
```